# Passed 10K but can't see "tools" button

Tags: support, 10k-tools

Last week I passed 10K rep but the "tools" button hasn't yet appeared on the top menu bar. The bar has only the following buttons:

| review | chat | meta | faq |

However, I can see the tools page using https://english.stackexchange.com/tools.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should click on *review*, and then somewhere below toggle to *tools*. I discovered this myself after playing around for a while!

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you will need to click on "review" link you see on the top, and then on the "tools" tab you see on that page.

[image: screenshot]

The link that you see on the top can be "review" or "tools," depending from the tab you last selected on that page: When you selected the "tools" tab, the link on the top will be "tools" too; when you selected the "review" tab, the link on the top will be "review" too.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Stack Exchange code remembers which tab you selected, and will show the link on the top bar basing on that every time you log in to the site.